# is there any I can exclude attitube from results on get_item using boto3

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I would like to exclude `user_name` from my response of get_item.
Below is my query

```
   results = TABLE.get_item(
        Key={
            'id': is,
        }
    )
    return results['Item']
```

How can I exclude `user_name` from this response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DynamoDB [GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) operation has a `ProjectionExpression` parameter (or the archaic `AttributesToGet` parameter) which can be used to only request specific attributes, but there is no syntax to specific that you want all the attributes **except** one specific attribute.

If your items do not have a known list of attributes, all you can do in this case is to just retrieve the entire item with all its attributes, and then remove the `user_name` attribute from the response object, in Python.

Usually, there is no downside to doing this; Note that in any case you pay for the read based on the entire item's size - regardless of which attributes you ask to retrieve. So when the attribute you wish to exclude is small, the networking overhead is small anyway, and when the attribute you wish to exclude is large, you'll be paying for reading it anyway - so you should probably change your data model.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do end up specifying which attributes to return it will not cut down costs. Dynamodb will always return all attributes on the item requested and then filter from there.